# Authentication and authorization using Google login in Drools' business-central

Tags: drools

My organization has decided to use Drools as a decision management framework. We are using the new UI business-central which is deployed as a WAR file in WildFly server for managing the rules and the assets related to the rules.

We have licensed Gsuite for our emails and other activities. We want to use Google login for the users of the business-central system instead of the username and password-based auth provided.

One way to do it is by using a Keycloak server which will provide us a way to manage users and authentication. But we do not want to maintain an extra server just for authentication.

Can someone please help me in achieving this authentication? Also, it would be helpful if I can know in advance the pitfalls of such a type of authentication approach.

Here are the version details for the drools system:

Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
Drools: 7.33.0.Final

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of trial and error and quite a bit of googling around. I have reached the conclusion that providing social login in business-central should be done via Keycloak if you are using Wildfly. 
There are a lot of security-related features that you will get out of the box and you won't have to tweak around the drools code and later on finding out that you have missed a use case.